# dojo closest on clear element

Tags: dojo, closest

I get element from HTML handler, like:

```
<tr data-products=true>
    <input type='text' oninput='save(event)'/>
</tr>
```

And I want get closest element, I try:

```
require(
[
    "dojo/query",
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dojo/dom-style",
    "dojo/NodeList-dom",
    "dojo/NodeList-data",
    "dojo/NodeList-traverse",
    "dojo/domReady!"
],
function(query, lang, style){
    lang.mixin(event.target, query()); // add functions to element
    style.set(event.target.closest('tr'), 'border', '1px solid red');
}
```

How I can wrap element (add methods like jQuery `$(event.target)`) or use other functions?

[sorry, this is not implementation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/node.html)

Comment: The following should do the trick. `query(event.target).closest('tr').style("border", "1px solid red");`. You do not have to use lang.mixin. query returns nodelist with dom functions. see [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/query.html) for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick.

```
query(event.target).closest('tr').style("border", "1px solid red");
```

You do not have to use lang.mixin.
query returns nodelist with dom functions.
 
see [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/NodeList-traverse.html) and [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/query.html) for details